# EventTrigger с двумя условиями

Tags: wpf, события, триггер

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста дописать триггер. Данный триггер меняет Opacity  компонента (StackPanel) с 0 до 70% (т.е. делает компонент видимым) при нажатии на него левой кнопки мыши.

Мне нужно доработать триггер так, чтобы при **следующем нажатии левой кнопки мыши** - Opacity опять "уходила" в 0 (компонент становился невидимым). То есть триггер должен отлавливать 2 условия:

1. событие MouseLeftButtonDown
2. Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"

Можно ли делать EventTrigger с двумя условиями?

Как в DataTrigger "забиндить" событие MouseLeftButtonDown?

```
<Style x:Key="Pic_Panel_Visibility" TargetType="StackPanel">  
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>  
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>  
    <Style.Triggers>  
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown">  
            <EventTrigger.Actions>  
                <BeginStoryboard Name="BeginStory">  
                    <Storyboard>  
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"  
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0" To="0.7"/>  
                    </Storyboard>  
                </BeginStoryboard>  
            </EventTrigger.Actions>  
        </EventTrigger> 
        <!-- Тут нужен описанный в вопросе функционал -->
    </Style.Triggers>  
</Style>
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Когда столкнулся с чем-то подобным около года назад, то решил реализовал через code-behind (не вижу ничего плохого и сейчас так сделать - работа идет только с визуальной частью). Но любопытно узнать решение через триггеры.

Comment: Подозреваю, что одной только разметкой не справиться, придется писать код

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без code-behind, почти.

Вам нужно сделать attached property, значение которого будет выставляться через EventTrigger, в вашем случае при нажатии левой кнопки мыши.

А рядом положить MultiTrigger, который будет срабатывать при условии наличия значения в упомянутом выше свойстве.

UPD: код.

Модель:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isPropertySet;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public Model()
    {
        SetPropertyCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            IsPropertySet = !IsPropertySet;
        });
    }

    public bool IsPropertySet
    {
        get { return _isPropertySet; }
        set
        {
            _isPropertySet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPropertySet));
        }
    }

    public ICommand SetPropertyCommand { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Model />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                Value="0.1" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsPropertySet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                   Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="80"
                Height="80" Background="Red">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetPropertyCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Вам нужен один триггер на событие для установки свойства, и один триггер, который биндится на это свойство и выставляет нужное значение Opacity.

Comment: Отвечайте кодом сразу. А лучше готовым простым примером, который можно запустить и посмотреть.

Comment: Я понимаю, у меня на компьютере, с которого отвечаю, нет пока студии. Завтра буду уже с примерами отвечать

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста кодом, я еще новичок и для меня трудны такого рода хитросплетения.

Comment: Добавил пример кода